# yadcf "select_type_options" not effective for Chosen

Tags: datatables, jquery-chosen, yadcf

I am using yadcf to create a filter with `"select_type":"chosen"`in a separate large container. As the chosen-Dropdown was rendered too small, I added `"select_type_options":"width:200px;"` but that has not had any effect. Does that info need to be provided in a different format - or have I hit a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a bug, `select_type_options` property type is an object, so you should feed it an object value with key/value

Fix your code from

`"select_type_options":"width:200px;"`

into

`select_type_options: { width: '200px;' }`

See from docs:

```
* select_type_options
    Required:           false
    Type:               Object
    Default value:      {}
    Description:        This parameter will be passed "as is" to the Chosen/Select2 plugin constructor
```

You can also find this in the [showcase](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_chosen.html) code snippet

Comment: It was a bug. But I committed it ;-)  Thanks Daniel :-)